# GCC not using Boost folder include flag

Tags: macos, gcc, boost, makefile

I have a project that includes a library that uses boost 1.57, which is also included. However, the GCC compiler (default Xcode CLI tools v6.0 GCC version 4.2.1) does NOT pick up boosts include directory while it DOES pick up other directories. What is going on here?

This is the final GCC command being issued:

```
gcc -g -stdlib=libstdc++ -Wall -Wno-error -ferror-limit=1000 -fmessage-length=0 
-DHCUBE_NOGUI -DTIXML_USE_STL -DMACOS -mmacosx-version-min=10.5 -arch i386 -arch x86_64 
-I/Applications/Webots6.3.0/include/controller/c 
-I/Users/mtw800/experimentSuite/experiment/../HyperNEAT/tinyxmldll/include 
-I/Users/mtw800/experimentSuite/experiment/../HyperNEAT/NE/HyperNEAT/NEAT/include 
-I/Users/mtw800/experimentSuite/experiment/../HyperNEAT/JGTL/include 
-I/Users/mtw800/experimentSuite/experiment/../HyperNEAT/boost_1_57_0/boost/ -DXML1 
-c ModHyperNEAT/mod_ctrler7.cpp  -o controllers/mod_ctrler7_1.o
```

The error GCC gives me:

```
In file included from ModHyperNEAT/mod_ctrler7.cpp:30:
In file included from /Users/mtw800/experimentSuite/experiment/../HyperNEAT/NE/HyperNEAT/NEAT/include/NEAT.h:4:
In file included from /Users/mtw800/experimentSuite/experiment/../HyperNEAT/NE/HyperNEAT/NEAT/include/NEAT_Globals.h:4:
/Users/mtw800/experimentSuite/experiment/../HyperNEAT/NE/HyperNEAT/NEAT/include/NEAT_Defines.h:23:10: 
fatal error: 'boost/shared_ptr.hpp' file not found
#include <boost/shared_ptr.hpp>
     ^
1 error generated.
make: *** [experiment-modular] Error 1
```

The boost include path:

```
-I/Users/mtw800/experimentSuite/experiment/../HyperNEAT/boost_1_57_0/boost/
```

exists and invoking a `` find `pwd` -name shared_ptr.hpp `` gives the following result:

```
MW-020708:boost_1_57_0 mtw800$ pwd
/Users/mtw800/experimentSuite/HyperNEAT/boost_1_57_0
MW-020708:boost_1_57_0 mtw800$ find `pwd` -name shared_ptr.hpp
/Users/mtw800/experimentSuite/HyperNEAT/boost_1_57_0/boost/asio/detail/shared_ptr.hpp
/Users/mtw800/experimentSuite/HyperNEAT/boost_1_57_0/boost/interprocess/smart_ptr/shared_ptr.hpp
/Users/mtw800/experimentSuite/HyperNEAT/boost_1_57_0/boost/serialization/shared_ptr.hpp
/Users/mtw800/experimentSuite/HyperNEAT/boost_1_57_0/boost/shared_ptr.hpp
/Users/mtw800/experimentSuite/HyperNEAT/boost_1_57_0/boost/smart_ptr/shared_ptr.hpp
/Users/mtw800/experimentSuite/HyperNEAT/boost_1_57_0/boost/thread/csbl/memory/shared_ptr.hpp
```

So I know that the boost include library is there, the path is correct and even the header file for shared_ptr is there. Why is GCC not picking up my include folder path?

I have tested that the other include paths ARE being picked up (as they should) by removing all -I flags and re-adding them when GCC gave errors that it could not find them.

The curious thing is, that if i install boost with home-brew, and further change nothing, that my compile script just 'works', because homebrew probably links boost into directories that are searched by GCC by default. That's great, however, I don't want GCC to use the homebrew boost because it has to compile on a system that does NOT use homebrew. What do I do? Why is GCC pestering me by only excluding one include folder and not all the others? what kind of non-deterministic compiler automagick is going on here?

I am using OSX Yosemite 10.10, mentioned Xcode developer tools above. The other computer uses the same OSX and the same GCC (same Xcode dev tools).

Comment: Have you tried removing the last path element (`boost`) from `-I/Users/mtw800/.../HyperNEAT/boost_1_57_0/boost/`?

Comment: Are you kidding me, that seemed to have been the culprit! If you copy paste it as answer, i'll accept it as answer later!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to remove the last element (`boost`) from:

```
-I/Users/mtw800/experimentSuite/experiment/../HyperNEAT/boost_1_57_0/boost/
```

Given source files use `#include <boost/whatever.h>`, the preprocessor expects to find the `boost` sub-directory when it searches that include directory.